# $U$ sub-space of $R^n$. Prove that $\forall x \in R^n$, $x \bullet p \le \|x\|^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

$U$ is a sub-space of $R^n$. **Prove** that $\forall x \in R^n$, $x \bullet p \le \|x\|^2$. $p$ is the projection of $x$ on $U$. Give a condition on $x$ that proves equality.

Well, I know that $\|x\|^2 = x \bullet x$ , Thus $x \bullet p \le x \bullet x$.

I know that $Proj._{U} x = \frac{x \bullet u}{u \bullet u}u$.

Do I need to write $u$ in the projection differently? I mean, U is a subpace, and you can make a scalar multiplication with subspace, meaning that possibly I need to say that every subspace has a basis, let's assume it is $a_1,..,a_n$. and change that accordingly $U = sp\{a_1,...,a_n\}$.

and for the condition in the end $p = x$.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What's the difference between "$n$" and "$N$"? Is "$\bullet$" the usual dot product?

Comment: $n = N$, and $\bullet$ is scalar multiplication. "dot"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "projection" you mean the orthogonal projection. If this is the case, we have that 
$$\Vert x-p\Vert^2+\Vert p \Vert ^2=\Vert x \Vert^2.$$
Hence, $\Vert p \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert.$
Therefore, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$|x \bullet p| \leq \Vert x\Vert \Vert p \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert \Vert x \Vert=\Vert x \Vert^2$.

Comment: I understand your equation. but how will I prove that $x \bullet p \le x \bullet x$. do I need to show that $x \bullet p \le ||x-p||^2 + ||p||^2$ ? and how will I prove equality? also, I didn't understand why $||p|| \le ||x||$. Please, if you can expand your answer I'll be very grateful, I want to understand this.

Comment: @Ilan, the vectors $p$ and $x-p$ form a right triangle with hypotenuse $x$. That's why $\|p\|\le \|x\|$, for example. What is your *definition* of the projection $p$? It should be (the unique) vector in $U$ so that $x-p$ is in $U^\perp$, i.e., orthogonal to all vectors in $U$.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I see. And what about equality? If and only if $||x|| = ||p||$ ?

Comment: Yes, literally think Pythagorean Theorem.